# How to set the default ComboBox selection inside my XAML code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

How can I set the default selection of my ComboBox right inside my XAML code? This is what the code of my ComboBox looks like:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0">           
  <ComboBoxItem>My first item</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In my C# code, I always used to set the default value of the ComboBox like this:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in my XAML code?

Comment: Yes, it is. Set `SelectedIndex` in XAML.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" SelectedIndex="0" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0">
        <ComboBoxItem>My first item</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

I hope this will help